# Is Thor indestructible?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, especially, Thor has a monumental battle in the arena with the Hulk receiving not physical damage (ok he got knocked out but didn't even get a black eye) yet in his fight with Hela he loses an eye and gets stabbed in the back a few times. Does he receive this damage because he is related to Hela therefore they can damage each other, or because he is in Asgard?

Comment: In the latest film he nearly died

Comment: Nearly but not quite

Comment: It's worth noting that any injuries received from the hulk would be in the form of blunt force trauma which is often much less obvious than getting cut/stabbed. Especially if asguardians don't visibly bruise (we have no reason to think they do, i don't think)

Comment: Don't bruise? Do we know this for sure! What about a bloody nose?

Comment: The title and body of this question don't match.

Comment: "Tell me... do you bruise?"

Comment: Only if he dies.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thor [acknowledges](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War) his own mortality in *Avengers: Infinity War*:

> **Thor:** You know, I'm 1,500 years old. I've killed twice as many enemies as that, and every one of them would have rather **killed me**, but none succeeded. I'm only alive because Fate wants me alive. Thanos is just the latest in a long line of bastards, and he'll be the latest to feel my vengeance. Fate wills it so.

In the same movie, Thor also:

> took the full heat of the dying star when making Stormbreaker and was knocked out for several moments, with the implication that this almost killed him.

Therefore, it stands to reason that he is not indestructible.

Regarding the specific movie, *Thor: Ragnarok*, it is actually said that Hela is stronger than all other living Asgardians at the [moment](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Thor:_Ragnarok):

> **Loki:** She's stronger than both of us. She's stronger than you. You don't stand a chance.

Therefore, since Hela quite easily tore out Thor's eye, then she could also probably fatally wound him and indeed that seems to be her intent in the movie.

Comment: I get that but immortal and indestructible are different. Getting your head pounded on by the Hulk without a scratch when soon after you loose an eye seems weird.

Comment: It depends on who is doing the pounding, Hela or Hulk. Arguably, the former is more powerful.

Comment: Does it matter? Hela took his eye out, Hulk KO'd him and fatally wounded but he still manages to jump up 2 minutes later with hardly a mark (although Banner jumps out the ship onto the Bifrost bridge, lands on his face and gets up 2 minutes later)

Comment: @Seamusthedog - I can understand your question and point of view on the matter, but he is not indestructible given he lost an eye. Also, dealing damage to an Asgardian is not based upon race or relation, given that Thor's mother (Frigga) was killed by the elves... Regarding Hulk and Hela, Hulk only got a couple blunt shots in where Thor had no armor during their entire fight vs. Hela who deliberately went for his eye with a blade. As well, even Loki, who is not Asgardian, showed no physical signs after battling with hulk... There is a reason war developed the sword to replace the first...

Comment: @Odin1806 just wondering if there is something more to it than 'movie magic'. Everyone in the MCU takes a major kicking at some point and no one really shows any signs of it. Re Hulk fight, Hulk landed on his unarmoured head from about 100 ft.....

Comment: @Seamusthedog that's a known quality of the Hulk/Banner relationship though.  Banner can shoot himself in the head, and the Hulk spits out the bullet.

Comment: @Seamusthedog, it's pretty obvious that the movies don't follow physics as we understand them. See: Capt America's solid shield "absorbs blows", but he can still hit with it....

Comment: @Seamusthedog: vanilla humans like Hawkeye, Black Widow, and Tony Stark (outside the suit) haven't survived anything really implausible on screen, unless I'm forgetting something.  Maybe some explosions, but that falls into the Hollywood-explosions category of error, not "indestructible heros / plot armor".

Comment: I'm not as well read as most people here so I appreciate all responses. I ask silly questions because sometime the obvious is overlooked. In short, being dumb pays of sometimes. I've learned a lot through this site so far!!

Comment: @Seamusthedog I'm glad we were able to help! If you think you are covered by my answer, please consider accepting it :)

Comment: @Seamusthedog - Not a problem!... that is what this site exists for!